# How to avert "deadlock detected" issue on Postgres + Sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

Here's my code on the offending lines of code:

```
webdb.begin(subtransactions=True)
(webdb.query(Proxy).filter(Proxy.service_token == service_token)).update(
    {Proxy.date_deleted_utc: datetime.datetime.utcnow()},
    synchronize_session="fetch"
)
webdb.commit()
```

I've tried to start a subtransaction, and added fetch for synchronization.

But I still get this error:

```
DBAPIError: (TransactionRollbackError) deadlock detected
DETAIL:  Process 61086 waits for ExclusiveLock on tuple (7217,55) of relation 626383 of database 380717; blocked by process 61094.
Process 61094 waits for ShareLock on transaction 55622134; blocked by process 61088.
Process 61088 waits for ShareLock on transaction 55622141; blocked by process 61086.
HINT:  See server log for query details.
'UPDATE proxies SET date_deleted_utc=%(date_deleted_utc)s WHERE proxies.service_token = %(service_token_1)s' {'date_deleted_utc': datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 2, 12, 57, 23, 2358), 'service_token_1': u'3733a37e-2094-11e5-90b7-0242ac110080'}
```

What else can I do?

Comment: You generally avoid deadlocks by ensuring that all processes acquire their locks (i.e. update their records) in the same order. No idea how this is done in SQLAlchemy, sorry...

Comment: @NickBarnes: hence the subtransaction.

Comment: Wait, is there some outer transaction making other changes? You'll have to show the whole thing. You need to be modifying at least two records to cause a deadlock, and there's nothing special about the one which triggered the error message.